# Coffeescript - loop only if array exists

Tags: coffeescript

I want to iterate over array only if it exists.
Can this be a one-liner?

```
if array
    doSmth() for i in array
```

Answer (score 1):

hha! I've just discovered that I can do this

```
if array then doSmth() for i in array
```

And also this

```
if array then for i in array
        foo = 1
        bar = 2
        baz = 3
```

So simple...

Answer (score 1):

For a short loop like that I think the postfix-if would be more idiomatic:

```
doSmth() for i in array if array
```